# TALEND - DEFAULT CONFIGURATION

Tags: configuration, esb, talend

I'm looking for default Talend (I use Talend Open Studio for ESB 6.1.0) configuration. I cannot find it in doc. I need to know this:

1) Default HTTP transport. Is it a standard HTTP (Java I/O) or HTTP-NIO (Java, I/O non-blocking)?

2) Default threds, pool threading etc.

3) Default Java (JVM) parameters (XX:PermSize, XX:MaxPermSize etc).

Maybe someone know where I can find some information about it?

Answer (score 1):

For 3), the default parameters are configured in the .ini file linked to the .exe file used to launch the studio.

Here is some more info about it : 
https://help.talend.com/display/KB/Allocating+more+memory+to+Talend+Studio

I don't have any info regarding your other questions.

Comment: Thanks for this link!

Answer (score 1):

The JVM parameters are set at a studio level but can be overridden at the job level.

1. You can use the .ini file located in your studio installation folder.  Choose the .ini based on the studio you are running.
2. You can change at the studio level settings by clicking Window-->preferences.  See screen shot for the rest.

   [image]
3. Each job can be overridden in the run tab -->advanced settings

[image]